# How to PASS a html input field TO axios javascript code?

Tags: javascript, html, axios

I need plain/regular html form with a dropdown input field, called TYPES. 
Then I need the axios code I got from a codepen, to "receive" the TYPES value, that the user selected.  I don't understand how the html form input field is sent to the axios code?

The next steps are working, but I can't pass in the TYPES value. THanks

I know how to make a form.

I know php code.  (( fyi. example.com/getimages.php?cat=TYPES, this is working, but I need 'types' to be the passed in value))

I'm not good at axios or javascript.

***** HTML code *****

```
input: <input type="text" name="TYPES"  id="TYPES">
<button onclick=“findimages()">Search</button>
```

***** AXIOS code from a codepen *****

```
(function($) {


.... <other code>

 const fetchImages = (count = 10) => {

   axios.
   get(`https://example.com/getimages.php?cat=TYPES`).
   then(res => {
     setImages([...images, ...res.data]);
     setIsLoaded(true);

     console.log(images);
   });
 };

.... <other code>

};

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(Collage, null), 
document.getElementById("root"));

} )( jQuery );
```

If the search button on the html form can "call/send/pass" the axios code AND pass in the TYPES value... all will be great!

Comment: What you could do is `let types = document.getElementById("TYPES").value;` or if you are using JQuery `let value = $("#TYPES").val();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have some formatting/character coding issues with your example. `<button onclick=“findimages()">` is using incorrect quotes `(")`, and is also not calling `fetchImages()`. Also you mentioned `"dropdown input"`, so I'm not sure if you meant a `select dropdown`, or are just referring to a normal `input text box`. I added both for example purposes.

You can change out the `exampleURL` variable to pass in `type_select` instead of `type_input` if you want. This axios request will just hit an example JSON API and return `{"response" : 200}`, but you should see the `cat` variable passed in the request URL with TEST as the value.

```js
const fetchImages = (count = 10) => {

  let type_input = document.getElementById('types_input').value;
  let type_select = document.getElementById('types_select').value;

  // URL: 'https://example.com/getimages.php?cat=' + type_input;
  let exampleURL = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/7yftn?cat=' + type_input;

  axios.
  get(exampleURL).
  then(res => {
    console.log(res);
    // setImages([...images, ...res.data]);
    // setIsLoaded(true);
    // console.log(images);
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.0/axios.min.js"></script>
<select name="types_select" id="types_select">
  <option value="">-Select Type-</option>
  <option value="Type 1">Type 1</option>
  <option value="Type 2">Type 2</option>
</select>
<br/>
<input type="text" name="types_input" id="types_input" value="TEST" />
<br/>
<button onclick="fetchImages()">Search</button>
```

Comment: SWEET!!!! your types_input  field is being passed to the axios code, but the search button isn't doing anything?  Meaning, the value 'TEST', is being received on the page load, initial load and php file is getting the value 'TEST' ==> which is awesome!!!

But it appears onclick="fetchImages() " isn't doing anything?

any thoughts on what to change? or try?

thank you Woodrow!!!

Comment: No. Clicking the button triggers the fetchImages() function which then calls the axios request and passes the input value of TEST along to the web request. You can switch out the default value of TEST that I put in there and put anything else you want and should see that pass along to the request when you click the search button.

Comment: Woodrow, wouldn't the search button 'refresh' that codepen?  My guess, the click is not calling fetchImages?

Comment: I would have to see what CodePen you're talking about. Looking at your posted code, it appears that you're using a search button which triggers an event to call an API to fetch images, etc.

Comment: the only thing not working is the search button? On my own code and the simple test in that codepen, 

so back to the original codepen code: 
https://codepen.io/Chuloo/pen/BMPXqy


I just added this:
    <button onclick="fetchImages()">Search</button>

        <div id="root">
    </div>

click the search would refresh or load up new images? right

Comment: Ah, ok. I see, looking at the Codepen, the React ```Collage``` component is calling ```React.useEffect(() => {   fetchImages();  }, []); ``` on load/initial render, and then the ```InfiniteScroll``` component passes into the ```next``` property the call to the same function ```fetchImages()``` to continue loading the next images on scroll.

Comment: great!  so what does that mean for my situation?  :)  I'm not good at javascript. What should the search button do or call?

Comment: I modified the original codepen (forked it), and added the search button and input value to the render function, and bound the search button to the fetchImages function. Inside fetchImages, I added the type variable to get the value of the textbox, and pass that as cat= to the API. Looks like API has reached rate limit for testing with unspash, but I see the code passing the param value to the request: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/orpyvO